# Read from text file with delimiter

Tags: c++, text-files, delimiter

I have a text file with an index of students that looks something like this:

```
Anna Baker
Class 1B
Long description text about the student lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
#####
Rick Bell
Class 2A
Long description text about the student lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.
#####
etc.
```

I have a class Student and I need to extract the information from the text file and put it in student objects.

```
class Student{
private:
  string name;
  string class;
  string description;
}
```

Name and class worked fine so far but I'm struggling with extracting the description text. "#####" serves as a delimiter. I use:

```
while (???){
   getline(inFile, word3);
   word3=word3.substr(0,word3.find(delimiter));
}
```

I need a while loop to read all the lines up to the delimiter and I can't find the right statement for it. Can you help me?

Comment: If the format of the input file is simple:read line by line and compare each line if it is the correct one. If the format is more difficult : a parser will have to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Quick look to [cpp reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)  suggets that the return value of std::string::find is std::string::npos when not foud. So you can use something like

```
bool continue = true;
while (continue)
{
   getline(inFile, word3);
   continue = word3.find(delimiter)) == std::string::npos;
 //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ifstream to read file, with

```
std::ifstream student_file("file.txt");
```

You can read file line by line using,

```
string info;
if(student_file.is_open()){
   while( getline(student_file, info) ) {
        if( info == "####")
           continue;
        else {
                //this is student info
        }
   }
}
```